# Response cannot post in python Requests

Tags: python, python-requests

I am trying to scrape all items from this website: https://www.sayurbox.com/category/vegetables-1-a0d03d59/sub-category/all

Here's my code

```
#get all libraries

import requests 
import json 
import pandas as pd
import re
from datetime import date

today = str(date.today())

slugcat="vegetables-1-a0d03d59"
url="https://www.sayurbox.com/graphql/v1?deduplicate=1"

headers = {
'authorization': str(authoId)}
payload=[{"operationName":"getCartItemCount",
            "variables":{"deliveryConfigId":DCId},
            "query":"query getCartItemCount($deliveryConfigId: ID!) {\n  cart(deliveryConfigId: $deliveryConfigId) {\n    id\n    count\n    __typename\n  }\n}"},
           {"operationName":"getProducts",
            "variables":{"deliveryConfigId":DCId,
                         "sortBy":"related_product",
                         "isInstantDelivery":False,
                         "slug":slugcat,
                         "first":12,
                         "abTestFeatures":[]},
            "query":"query getProducts($deliveryConfigId: ID!, $sortBy: CatalogueSortType!, $slug: String!, $after: String, $first: Int, $isInstantDelivery: Boolean, $abTestFeatures: [String!]) {\n  productsByCategoryOrSubcategoryAndDeliveryConfig(\n    deliveryConfigId: $deliveryConfigId\n    sortBy: $sortBy\n    slug: $slug\n    after: $after\n    first: $first\n    isInstantDelivery: $isInstantDelivery\n    abTestFeatures: $abTestFeatures\n  ) {\n    edges {\n      node {\n        ...ProductInfoFragment\n        __typename\n      }\n      __typename\n    }\n    pageInfo {\n      hasNextPage\n      endCursor\n      __typename\n    }\n    productBuilder\n    __typename\n  }\n}\n\nfragment ProductInfoFragment on Product {\n  id\n  uuid\n  deliveryConfigId\n  displayName\n  priceRanges\n  priceMin\n  priceMax\n  actualPriceMin\n  actualPriceMax\n  slug\n  label\n  isInstant\n  isInstantOnly\n  nextDayAvailability\n  heroImage\n  promo\n  discount\n  isDiscount\n  variantType\n  imageIds\n  isStockAvailable\n  defaultVariantSkuCode\n  quantitySoldFormatted\n  promotion {\n    quota\n    isShown\n    campaignId\n    __typename\n  }\n  productVariants {\n    productVariant {\n      id\n      skuCode\n      variantName\n      maxQty\n      isDiscount\n      stockAvailable\n      promotion {\n        quota\n        campaignId\n        isShown\n        __typename\n      }\n      __typename\n    }\n    pageInfo {\n      hasPreviousPage\n      hasNextPage\n      __typename\n    }\n    __typename\n  }\n  __typename\n}"},
           {"operationName":"getProducts",
            "variables":{"deliveryConfigId":DCId,
                         "sortBy":"related_product",
                         "isInstantDelivery":False,
                         "slug":slugcat,
                         "first":12,
                         "abTestFeatures":[],
                         "after":"YXJyYXljb25uZWN0aW9uOjEx"},
            "query":"query getProducts($deliveryConfigId: ID!, $sortBy: CatalogueSortType!, $slug: String!, $after: String, $first: Int, $isInstantDelivery: Boolean, $abTestFeatures: [String!]) {\n  productsByCategoryOrSubcategoryAndDeliveryConfig(\n    deliveryConfigId: $deliveryConfigId\n    sortBy: $sortBy\n    slug: $slug\n    after: $after\n    first: $first\n    isInstantDelivery: $isInstantDelivery\n    abTestFeatures: $abTestFeatures\n  ) {\n    edges {\n      node {\n        ...ProductInfoFragment\n        __typename\n      }\n      __typename\n    }\n    pageInfo {\n      hasNextPage\n      endCursor\n      __typename\n    }\n    productBuilder\n    __typename\n  }\n}\n\nfragment ProductInfoFragment on Product {\n  id\n  uuid\n  deliveryConfigId\n  displayName\n  priceRanges\n  priceMin\n  priceMax\n  actualPriceMin\n  actualPriceMax\n  slug\n  label\n  isInstant\n  isInstantOnly\n  nextDayAvailability\n  heroImage\n  promo\n  discount\n  isDiscount\n  variantType\n  imageIds\n  isStockAvailable\n  defaultVariantSkuCode\n  quantitySoldFormatted\n  promotion {\n    quota\n    isShown\n    campaignId\n    __typename\n  }\n  productVariants {\n    productVariant {\n      id\n      skuCode\n      variantName\n      maxQty\n      isDiscount\n      stockAvailable\n      promotion {\n        quota\n        campaignId\n        isShown\n        __typename\n      }\n      __typename\n    }\n    pageInfo {\n      hasPreviousPage\n      hasNextPage\n      __typename\n    }\n    __typename\n  }\n  __typename\n}"}]

payload=json.dumps(payload) 
response=requests.post(url,headers=headers,json=payload)
```

I got the authoId and deliverycodeID from inspect element source and pasted it. However it is not returning any 200 . I am guessing The way I put the payload is wrong. Can anyone help me with that?

I also tried to pass just the first "getProducts" only and don't know if it will work.

Comment: Have you tried `requests.get`?

Comment: looking at the inspect element the Request Method uses post

Comment: What response-code do you get then?

Comment: This code will only retrieve the first 12 items, as specified by `"first":12`. If you need to retrieve all items, you will have to keep making API requests while hasNextPage in the returned data is True.

Comment: currently the content error b'<!DOCTYPE html>\n<html lang="en">\n<head>\n<meta charset="utf-8">\n<title>Error</title>\n</head>\n<body>\n<pre>Cannot POST /category/vegetables-1-a0d03d59/sub-category/all</pre>\n</body>\n</html>\n'

Comment: I mean the response-code error? Error 404 ?

Comment: Also, maybe have a look at the request in your browser, and make shure you use the exact same request-headers. Python adds different headers by default.

Comment: yes the response code returns 404. I have paste everything exactly the way it is.